# Check that there are no tests with only in github action

Tags: bash, grep, github-actions, gitlab-ci.yml

I'm trying to add a check to github action that I don't have any `only`s in my Playwright tests.

This was the line I added to my e2e.yml file:

```
    - name: Check that no only is present
      run: >
      grep -r --include '*.spec.ts' 'test.only' . && echo 'Found at least one ONLY in tests' && exit 1
```

And the GitHub action is failing as it should.
But... this line also the action also fail if there are **No** `only's. Any Idea why?

Comment: Do you use a linter? https://github.com/playwright-community/eslint-plugin-playwright/blob/main/docs/rules/no-focused-test.md would be trivial to apply for example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @jonrsharpe for the good suggestion of using a linter to detect the 'only's. I'll admit it's a better strategy.

The problem with the github action was that a regex with no match exits with 1.

The solution was to add `|| true` so that the failed regex would exit as 0, but the successful would exit with 1:

```
    - name: Check that no only is present
      run: >
      grep -r --include '*.spec.ts' 'test.only' . && echo 'You have it.only() in your tests!' && exit 1 || true
```